# Hiding special links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide links having a special signature, i.e. having a substring "become-a-member":

```
<a href="../become-a-member.html">Sign Up</a><br/>
<a href="someothertarget">keep this link</a>
```

using this jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function(i,e) {
        h = $(e).attr("href");
        if (~h.indexOf("become-a-member")) $(e).hide();
    }); 
});
```

It fails, see https://jsfiddle.net/xq7Luwwn/

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Showing only the second link

Comment: ok, check my answer

Comment: Classic mistake. You can't just use jQuery, It's a plugin, you have to include it. See AKA's answer below:

Comment: ok, the jQuery include was missing in jsfiddle. So this topic is supposed to be closed.

Comment: Did it work now?

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have posted works well. You might be missing the `JQuery` plugin to include in the HTML file which you have also missed to include in the `jsfiddle`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function(i,e) {
        h = $(e).attr("href");
        if (~h.indexOf("become-a-member")) $(e).hide();
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="../become-a-member.html">Sign Up</a><br/>
<a href="someothertarget">keep this link</a>
```